# Unix SFTP renaming a file with timestamp being part of the filename

Tags: unix, sftp, unix-timestamp

in SFTP mode in Unix, is it possible to rename a file by appending a timestamp onto the current filename?

For example:

rename fileA.csv to fileA-2018-04-02-040404.csv

Thanks

Comment: The protocol lets you rename files on the remote server. What is your real question here?

Answer (score 0):

It's a little unclear why you're asking the question.  The short answer is 'yes'.  But then the question arises, how are you going to create the timestamp?  Do you want that to somehow happen automatically or programatically.  No sftp client I'ver heard of has built-in support for that.  So you can always do it 'by hand', but I'm guessing that's not what you want?

Comment: Can't upvote this as it doesn't answer a Q (IMHO) but, yes, not a well formulated Q. Maybe this would be better as a comment. Good luck.

Comment: what i was trying to do is to retrieve a file from a windows server to Unix using SFTP.Once I managed to do a "GET", I want to rename the file on the windows server.

but after reading through your explanation, I can't do it without invoking some type of shell command.